# Numpy C API integer scalar

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to use numpy C API in order to check object for integer type (numpy type as well as python integer). I'm doing the following:

Creating cython `test.pyx` with:

```py
cdef extern from "numpy/ndarrayobject.h":
    bint PyArray_IsIntegerScalar(obj)

def check_int(object obj):
    return PyArray_IsIntegerScalar(obj)
```

Compile it with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. With `setup.py` as:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize('test.pyx',
                          annotate=True,
                          language_level=3)
)
```

Then running `test.py` with following simplest content:

```py
import test
print(test.check_int(1.1))
```

But I'm receiving `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. What have I missed? Cannot find even [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#dealing-with-types) for `PyArray_IsIntegerScalar`. Simply found it in the numpy [code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ea965e4cd328fbcf76b03ff749ef06d2aa38c28b/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h#L52).

numpy 1.16.4
Cython 0.29.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [Numpy's `import_array` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html?highlight=import_array#importing-the-api) before you can use the Numpy C API. This means doing it at module initialization time (i.e. at the top, in global scope):

```
cimport numpy
numpy.import_array()

# your code goes here, unchanged
```

(You could also get `import_arrray` in your `cdef extern` block instead of cimport)

Comment: I was sure I missed something simple like that. But for me it is unclear why such basic things are stated almost in the bottom of the docs (that is why I missed it) - not right on the top (which I reread multiple times).

Comment: It isn't as obvious as it should be.